# mov 32bytes to 8bytes in assembly registery

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

lets says the values sets like this:

ESI=32604F35AF
EBX=0

now, we got this mov command:
mov bl, [esi]

now, my question is, what will happen, because I took 32bytes, and place it on 8bytes.
what will be the value of "bl", and why?

Comment: What do you think, and why? Hint: it's not going to be 32604F35AF because that does not fit.

Comment: I know, so what will be the answer and why?

Comment: `esi` is 32 bits. And that is 4 bytes. (notice **i** vs **y**). Bit is just 0 or 1, single cell with electricity current or not. Byte is group of 8 bits together. `mov bl, [esi]` does load 8 bits (1 byte) from memory, the value in `esi` is used indirectly, sent to the memory chip as an address value, where the 8 bits should be read from. To move that value of `esi` directly into `bl` you would have to do `mov ebx, esi` (no `[]`), and that would set also remaining upper 24 bits of `ebx`, not just `bl`, but `bl` would be `0xAF` (the low 8 bit part of `esi`). Register bits are physically in CPU.

Comment: *"what will be the value of "bl" "* - impossible to tell, as you didn't show content of memory (and you would have to provide also valid example value for `esi`, just 32 bits "wide", not 40 bits like in your post). You can learn to read individual bits from hexadecimal formatting quite easily, every hexadecimal digit is 4 bits: 0 = 0000, 1 = 0001, 2 = 0010, ... E = 1110, F = 1111. Then 2 hexadecimal digits are 8 bits = 1 byte. That's the reason why hexadecimal formatting is preferred default in debuggers, so it is easy for programmer to check particular byte/bits even in longer value.

Answer (score 1):

`mov bl,[esi]` does not try and shove the 32 bits of `esi` into `bl`. Instead it reads the byte of memory with the address in `esi` into `bl`.

E.g.

If memory looks like this:

```
Address   contents
00000000  00 11 22 23 44 65 86 77
00000008  18 29 6A 4B 1C 0D 0E 0F
```

And `esi` contains `00000007` then `bl` will be filled with the byte at that address. In this case `77`.

If you want to load esi into bl, you'll have to do that indirectly

```
mov ebx,esi       
and ebx,$000000FF     //discard upper 24 bits
```

Whenever square brackets `[]` are used in x86 it denotes a memory access, except when `lea` is used. `lea` simply performs calculations.